# Count all substrings of specific length throughout the string in python

Tags: python, string

I am given a string : 'stackoverflow'. 
Input should be a integer, for example lets say a=4.
What my code should do is, it should count length of substrings occuring at overlapping intervals of 4 that is (considering string 'stackoverflow')-

- String one : stac
- String two : tack
- String three : acko
- String four : ckov

and it goes on till the end of the string.
Then later I need to find the string that occurs most number of times.
So far, what I have done is -

```
def a_length():
    string=input('Enter string : ')
    substr=list('')
    a=input('Enter length of a : ')
    for i in range(len(string)):
        substr += string[i:i+a]
        print(substr)
```

What I am trying here is to get the a list of substrings present but it gives an error which I do not understand -

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'slice'

But this definately doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: unrelated, but why do you initialise a list as `list('')` instead of either `list()` or `[]`?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser : As of what I thought was, it is a list of strings. Thus, the list(''). In anyways it works both the ways, if you initialize it by '[]' or just by 'list()'.

Comment: `list('')` takes the string, and converts it to a list; it's an empty list simple because the string has no characters. For example `list('foo')` is the same as `['f', 'o', 'o']`. Lists can contain different types too (`[1, 'a']` is perfectly valid), so your syntax makes it look as though you've misunderstood something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string=input('Enter string : ')
substr=list('')
a=int(input('Enter length of a : '))
for i in range(len(string)):
    substr.append(string[i:i+a])
print(substr)
```

Be careful that in this way also strings "low", "ow" and "w" are generated

If you want to stop at "flow", substitute this line in the for loop

`for i in range(len(string)-a+1):`

Also, with list comprehension: `substr = [string[i:i+a] for i in range(len(string)-a+1)]`

Comment: This does not work, I tried this too earlier. Sorry!

Comment: Should also explain that you're passing the user input to `int`, as that seems to be the key difference

Comment: On my machine it works. Did you notice the `int()` when taking the `a` value from `input()` ?

Comment: @PMonti : Oops! I am extremely sorry, I misread your answer and it does work perfectly fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
s = input('Enter string')
a = int(input('Enter the interval'))
words_count = dict()
len1 = len(s)
i = 0
while i + a < len1:
  new_word = s[i:i+a]
  words_count[new_word] = words_count.get(new_word, 0) + 1
  i = i + 1


for word in words_count:
  print(word)
  print(words_count[word])
```

You can run my code here - https://repl.it/HdrX/1

Hope this help !

Comment: This one's a great code as well, the only thing is that I could not actually get the total of a specific occurence of a substring.

Comment: I actually cannot figure that out from PMonti 's code as well. If you can actually guide me to get that, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi Srk, so ya if you run my code, you will be able to get the count of each words as well, do you see the variable word_count initialised to dict(), so that is like a hash map to store the count of each word as - 'kav' -> '2' etc.

Comment: So in the for loop if you look closely this line - words_count[new_word] = words_count.get(new_word, 0) + 1 .... does the taks of calculating frequency of each word.

Comment: Yes I have exactly understood that, so what I did was took the string 'stackstackoverflow' as an input string. But even then, I get each substring number as 1. Any insights on that?

Comment: Let me take a look into it, may be I am missing something

Comment: Srk, if you run my code on this link - https://repl.it/HdrX/1  with string - 'stackstackoverflow' and interval = 4, it gives you this result:-stac
2
tack
2
acks
1
ckst
1
ksta
1
acko
1
ckov
1
kove
1
over
1
verf
1
erfl
1
rflo
1